# Web Filter in java EE

Tags: java, java-ee

Хочу сделать общий фильтр - для всех запросов и ответов.

1. Проверка на Origin и на присутствие определённых заголовках в запросах.

   Apply a filter for all URLs:

   ```
   @WebFilter("/*")
   public class MyFilter implements Filter {}
   ```

   Нашел данный способ для создание фильтра для всех урлов веб аппликации.
   Остался под вопросом сам механизм работы такого способа..

   Что именно будет происходить ?

   Любой запрос который будет исходить из моего домена, будет вначале проходить   через этот класс с его проверкой на наличие заголовков, а после удачной проверки уходить по своему URI ?
2. Также буду рад любым советам на создание хорошего фильтра для запросов и ответов, которые прибавят к безопасности !

Comment: В интернете можно найти что именно будет происходить в картинках. Пришлось немного напрячь воображение, чтобы понять как это работает цепочка фильтров. А так да. запрос приходит, потом может уйти, а может и остаться и вернуться, и ещё кте-что интересное  можно сделать. И ответ тоже будет проходить через тот же фильтр.

Comment: Что ты имеешь виду под "запрос может и остатся" ?

Comment: А то, что можно перекрыть дальнейшую обработку, если что-то не понравится.

Comment: А ок это я знаю. Думал может еще чего то намудрили))

Comment: Можешь дать ссылку на "чтобы понять как это работает цепочка фильтров" ?

Comment: http://otndnld.oracle.co.jp/document/products/as10g/101300/B25221_03/web.1013/b14426/filters.htm